# Proof for a first-order differential equation claim

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Claim: If $p(x)$ is a solution to a first-order differential equation in the form of $df/dx=g(f)$, then $p(x+c)$, with $c$ constant, is a solution as well.

I know the idea of the proof, but I am having trouble expressing it in a rigorous proof. Namely, my idea is that if we shift $p(x)$ to the left by $c$, then both the LHS and RHS will shift by $c$ (invoking the chain rule), so they are equal. Should I define $u=x+c$ and do a change of variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose $p(x)$ is a solution of $$\frac{dy}{dx} =g(y). \tag 1 $$  that means $$ p'(a) = g(p(a))\text{ for all $a$ in the domain of $p$.}\tag 2$$ in particular putting $a = x+c$ in $(2),$ we have $$(p(x+c))' = p'(x+c)= g(p(x+c)) $$ which says that $y=p(x+c)$ is a solution of $(1).$ we have used the chain rule in the first equality of the last equation.

the geometric reason is that the slope field $g(y)$ is translation invariant with respect to $x.$

Comment: Thanks @abel - what is the difference between $(p(x+c))'$ and $p'(x+c)$ in the first equality? Is the first a derivative with respect to $a$, and the latter with respect to $x$?

Comment: @FreshAir, the derivative is with respect to $x.$ the function $p(x+c)$ is a composition of two functions $p$ and $x+c.$ so we used the chain rule to find the derivative of $p(x+c)$ treated as a function of $x.$

Comment: abel, thanks, I'm still thinking about this, and I'll let you know if I have unresolved issues.